# Change project path in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to make some modifications on a Symfony project, but I can't do anything yet, because I get a

```
ErrorException: Warning: 
file_get_contents(/some/other/directory/here/src/ProjectName/Bundle/Resources/views/Default/login.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The paths always start with /some/other/directory/here/, but I don't need that part. I looked in the app folder since most of the application configs are there, but I can't find where I should modify the path.

Comment: This is suspicious: ProjectName/Bundle/Resources  I would have expected something like ProjectName/ACMEBundle/Resources.  You probably have a typo in your template file name.

Comment: I don't really see what is the difference. But that's not my problem, my problem is that it's trying to fetch the files from /some/other/directory/here/src/ProjectName/Bundle/Resources/views/Default/login.html.twig instead of here/src/ProjectName/Bundle/Resources/views/Default/login.html.twig

Comment: Clear the cache. You'll refresh the paths. You can't get a relative path btw, you'll always get a full path.

Comment: Do you mean my browser's cache? Or Symphony's cache? Because my browser cache is cleared and it's still not working.

Comment: Symfony cache. Your browser cache has nothing to do with server paths.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain cache files localed in the cache folder (`app/cache`) store absolute paths.

In `dev` and `test` environments cache folder is refreshed automatically, in `prod` it is not. Since you've got issues I'm guessing you're trying to use the `prod` environment.

Clear your cache :)

Answer (score 0):

if running cache:clear does not resolve the problem, you can manually delete it.Go to cache directory and delete the said file .If running cache:clear does not resolve your problem, your can do this

```
sudo rm -rf app/cache/*
sudo rm -rf app/logs/*
```

You can do this if it is permitted in your Operating system(Linux)